# How to split complex string which has [] using regex in java?

Tags: java, regex

String rule=`"$.technical.[?(@.fileType != 'null' && @.dateTimestamp!= 'null')] && $.business.[? 
(@.Modality == 'IMG')]";`

I need to split the above-mentioned rule with && which is outside the brackets.

Expected output after split should be

```
token[0]= $.technical.[?(@.fileType != 'null' && @.dateTimestamp!= 'null')]

token[1]= &&

token[2]= $.business.[?(@.Modality == 'IMG')]"
```

How to write a regex to split the above string to get the expected result?

Comment: What is your attempt so far?

Comment: Iam using regex - "(?<![&|])(?=[&|])|(?<=[&|])(?![&|])" to split but i am not getting expected output.  $.technical.[?(@.fileType != 'null' && @.dateTimestamp!= 'null')] && inside the brackets are also getting split.

Comment: You should consider `$.` starting characters to extract tokens instead `&&`.

Comment: Not possible to get the below expecetd result ?token[0]= $.technical.[?(@.fileType != 'null' && @.dateTimestamp!= 'null')]

token[1]= &&

token[2]= $.business.[?(@.Modality == 'IMG')]"

Answer (score 0):

`/(?<=\]).+&&/`

`(?<=\])` = positive lookbehind, means `&&` only counts when preceded by `]`
`.+` = any sequence
`&&` = your token

Comment: Thank you so much it worked for me.But i need capture the operator as well.with obove regex i get token[0]=$.technical.[?(@.fileid != 'null' && @.uriTimestamp != 'null')] , token[1]=$.business.[?(@.Modality == 'MR')] and i am missing to capture the '&&'.

Comment: is it not possible to get the below-expected result using split by passing required regex?token[0]= $.technical.[?(@.fileType != 'null' && @.dateTimestamp!= 'null')]

token[1]= &&

token[2]= $.business.[?(@.Modality == 'IMG')]"